# Is it possible to get the type from a generic, given as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, events, observable, type-safety

I created a function that takes an object of subscribers, as seen below.

```
public subscribers = {
    count: <EventEmitter<number>>new EventEmitter<number>(),
    staticCount: <EventEmitter<number>>new EventEmitter<number>()
};
```

This function waits for both observables to complete, and returns an object with the keys of the object it received, as value the emitted value from the EventEmitter.

```
type AnyType<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: any;
}

function ZipObservable<T extends { [name: string]: EventEmitter<any>}>
    (observables: T): Observable<AnyType<T>> {
    const m = CreateMapFromObject(observables);
    const o = new Subject<any>();

    Observable.zip(...Array.from(m.values())).subscribe((res) => {
        const keys = m.keys();
        const c = res.reduce((r, v) => {
            const k = <string>keys.next().value;
            r[k] = v;

            return r
        }, {});

        /**
         *
         */
        o.next(c);
        o.complete();
    });

    return o.asObservable();
}
```

My current problem is at the type of the value set in the returned object. The object its keys are typed (as you can see in the image).

I also want the type of the value to be set to number (in this case).
I created a type; `AnyType<T>` that's able to set the returned object its keys. Is it possible to also get it to set its value's type?

The type i want it to become, comes from the parameter, which receives a generic; `EventEmitter<number>`.

Working type safety for the returned object.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want `ZipObservable` to return an object of type `Observable<T>`, where the input parameter has the same keys as `T` but the values for each key `K` are `EventEmitter<T[K]>` (where `T[K]` is the type of the property value of the `K` key of type `T`).  That is definitely achievable, through [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types):

First let's define a mapped type which takes every property in `T` and converts it to an `EventEmitter<>` of the appropriate type:

```
type EventEmitters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: EventEmitter<T[K]>
}
```

Now the `ZipObservable` function signature can be written directly (I will leave the implementation up to you):

```
declare function ZipObservable<T>(eventEmitters: EventEmitters<T>): Observable<T>;
```

And it works because of inference from mapped types:

```
const ret = ZipObservable(subscribers).subscribe(r => r.count * 3); // no error
```

Hope that helps; good luck!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll accept your answer, got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850110/8806284)

You got me on the right path. Your code worked. It removed my type safety though, so i tweaked it a little bit.

**--** **EDIT**

It didn't remove my type safety. My editor just doesn't recognize the keys on the returned object. It does when i use the code below.

```
type EmittedReturnType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}

type EventEmitters<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: EventEmitter<T[K]>
}
```

So,

I created two types; First type to be the parameter type. The second type to be the return type.

```
declare function ZipObservable<T>(observables: EventEmitters<T>): Observable<EmittedReturnType<T>>
```

Which results in;

[A type safe object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jroFj.png)

[A type safe assign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQa0K.png)

Comment: Your `EmittedReturnType<T>` definition is essentially just `T`, and therefore just a roundabout and verbose version of the code I wrote.  I think you are mistaken about my code "removing type safety" (see the line labelled `no error`.)  If I try assigning a string to `r.count` in my code I get the same error you have.  Good luck again!

Comment: You're right. Although my editor (PhpStorm) doesn't recognize the keys as keys on the returned object without `EmittedReturnType<T>`, weird. It does give an error when trying to assign a string to it.